# How to deal with asynchronous props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, react-lifecycle

I can't quite wrap my head around this.

I'm having to pass data that's fetched asynchronously. Issue is, the props are asynchronous as well. Here's a simplified version of the component:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react'
import CSVLink from 'react-csv'
import generateData from './customApi/generateData

type Props = { job?: JobType | undefined }
type State = { csvData: string[][] }

class MyComponent extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    csvData = [],
  }

  generateCsv = async (jobId: string) => {
    const csvData = await generateData(jobId)
    this.setState({ csvData })
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { job } = this.props
    await this.generateCsv(job.id)
  }

  render() {
    const { csvData } = this.state

    return (
       <CSVLink data={csvData}>
          <p>Download csv</p>
       </CSVLink>
    )
  }
}

export default connectFirestore(
   (db, params) => ({ getJob(db, params.id) })
)
```

Basically my props are fetched from an API call to firestore, so it takes a while to load the job. Issue is, when I'm trying to pass the `jobId` inside the `async componentDidMount()`, it ends up passing `undefined`, because the `job` `props` are not loaded yet.

I don't link the whole passing state to async call business going on, but I can't think of any other way, how I would passing the `csvData` from the `generateDate()` async call only once the `Promise` is resolved.

I guess the easiest way to approach this would be, **to perhaps somehow check if the props inside the `componentDidMount()` are already fetched?**

What would be the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the optimal solution, but it works.

I've decided to use [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdat) life-cycle method, where I'm comparing whether the props have already update and once they did, I'm calling the asynchornous function for generating the csv data.

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props) {
  if (prevProps !== this.props && !!this.props) {
    const { job } = this.props
    if (job) {
      await this.generateCsv(job.id)
    }
  }
}
```

This way we generate new data every time the data inside the `props.job` changed and also we don't attempt to call `generateCsv()` on undefined while it's still being fetched from firestore.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to implement the constructor where the props are set

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     csvData = [],
  };
}

componentDidMount(){
  //This will work
  console.log(this.props.job);
};
```

Comment: While I do agree constructor shouldn't be omitted, this will still leave `props.job` as `undefined`  on the initial render

Answer (score 0):

If `job` property should by async, do it async: rather than passing a value which will change in future, you can pass a `Promise` which resolves with the id, than change your `componentDidMount` as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const id = await this.props.job;
    this.generateCsv(id)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to call await in a synchronous `componentDidMount()`, also `await this.props.job` wouldn't do anything since it's not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the code inside your parent component, I imagine that you are making the API call there, as you are passing this data as props in this component you are showing to us.

I also imagine that you are making the API call with the fetch command, which can have a .then(()=>{}) method triggered when the API call finished loading, after that you can change the state of that component carrying the API fetched data and THEN render this child. Something I used recently for my project was to load from API, update state and conditionally render the child component, which will not know I made an API call because I am passing already loaded data. Normally while it is waiting I put something like this:

```
if(this.state.dataFetched == null)
   return(<h1>Loading page...</h1>)
else return <childComponent loadedData = {this.state.dataFetched}/>
```

And then access that data as this.props.loadedData